# Proof that if m divides any two sequential Fibonacci numbers it must be 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, divisibility

I did a proof to show that:

If $m|F_n$ and $m|F_{n+1}$ then $m=1$

My approach was to show that if $m|F_n$ and $m|F_{n+1}$ then $m|F_{n-1}$ which means that $m$ divides every Fibonacci number which means it divides $F_1$ which means it divides 1.

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: This seems like a pretty easy approach. What about about this proof seemed too complicated, so that it should be eliminated in another approach?

Comment: This argument shows that the claim is almost trivial. Which further simplification do you expect ? You could use that $\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}$ are the convergents of $[1,1,1,\cdots]$ and they are always in lowest terms , a very elegant approach , but to prove this all rigorously is surely not easier.

Comment: Another observation (clearly related): Euclid's algorithm directly shows the GCD is $1$.

Answer (score 3):

I think your approach is probably the easiest one. However, if you are familiar with the fact that
$$F_{n+1}\cdot F_{n-1} - F_n^2 = \pm 1$$
then you can immediately conclude that $\gcd(F_n,F_{n+1}) = 1$ (recall that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ *iff* there exists $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t $xa+yb=1$).

Comment: In general: $\gcd(F_n,F_m) = F_{\gcd(n,m)}$.

Comment: In fact using Cassini's identity is equivalent to the OP's proof (it's essentially an inductive extension of it - see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

That's likely simplest. Generally we can show that the gcd of $k$ consecutive elements (satisfying a $k$'th order linear recurrence) is *constant* *if* the recurrence is *bi-monic* (first & last coef's are $\color{#c00}{\bf \pm1}$), hence all such gcds are equal to the gcd of the *initial* $k$ elements (so, e.g. for the Fibonacci sequence this yields  $\,\gcd(F_{n+1},F_{n+2}) = \gcd(F_1,F_2) = \gcd(1,1) = 1)$

**Theorem** $ $ If the integer sequence $\,a_i$ satisfies the below $\color{#c00}{\text{bi-monic}}$ recurrence for all $n\ge 1$
$$ \color{#c00}{\bf 1}\:\! a_{n+k} = c_{n+k-1} a_{n+k-1} + \cdots + c_1 a_{n+1} \color{#c00}{\bf \pm 1}\:\! a_n,\ \ c_i\in\Bbb Z\quad$$

then this implies: $\  \gcd(a_{n+1},\ldots,a_{n+k}) = \gcd(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k)\ $ for all $\,n\ge 0$

**Proof** $\ $ We induct on $n$. Base case $\,n=0\,$ is clear. Else by by $\rm\color{#0af}{GMR}$ = [gcd mod reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3893224/242)

$\qquad\begin{align}
&\gcd(\ \ \ \ \ \ a_{n+1},a_{n+2},\ldots,a_{n+k-1},\,a_{n+k})\\[.2em] 
=\, &\gcd(\ \ \ \ \ \ \color{#90f}{a_{n+1}},\color{#0a0}{a_{n+2}},\ldots,\color{#c00}{a_{n+k-1}},\,\pm a_n + c_1 \color{#90f}{a_{n+1}} + c_{2} \color{#0a0}{a_{n+2}} + \cdots + c_{n+k-1} \color{#c00}{a_{n+k-1}})\\[.2em] 
=\, &\gcd(\ \ \ \ \ \ a_{n+1},a_{n+2},\ldots,a_{n+k-1},\,\pm \color{darkorange}{a_n})\ \ {\rm by\  \rm\color{#0af}{GMR}}\\[.2em] 
=\, &\gcd(\color{darkorange}{a_n},a_{n+1},a_{n+2},\ldots,a_{n+k-1})\\[.2em] 
=\, &\gcd(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k)\ \ {\rm by\ induction}
\end{align}$

**Generally** if the shift map $S_n$ on such $k$ tuples is linear and unimodular $(\det S_n =\pm1)$

$$S_n \begin{bmatrix} a_{n+k}\\ \vdots\\ a_n \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_{n+k+1}\\ \vdots\\ a_{n+1} \end{bmatrix},\ \ \det(S_n) = \pm1$$

then again the gcd of $k$ consecutive elements remains constant, with proof a straightforward generalization of [the $k=2$ case](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/52409/242). Fibonacci's are the special case $S_n = \begin{bmatrix}1 \!&\! 1\\ 1 \!&\! 0\end{bmatrix}$ and the proof by Cassini's identity (or addition law) in G.G's answer is a special case of this, e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/608548/242).

---

It can also be viewed as special case $\,j = k\!+\!1\,$ of the [strong divisibility property of the Fibonacci's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/60353/242)

$$\gcd(F_j,F_k) = F_{\gcd(j,k)}\qquad$$

Although the linked inductive proof of this is not much more difficult, its *discovery* likely is.