# Help on a simple-seeming modular arithmetic question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Suppose $a$ and $b$ are positive integers such that $a^2 + b^2$ is even and $a^3 + b^3$ is a multiple of 3. What is the largest positive integer that must divide $a^5 + b^5$?

My work so far is as follows:

If $a^2 + b^2$ is even, then $a$ being even implies $b$ being even, and $a$ being odd implies $b$ being odd (and vice versa). That is, $a \equiv b$ (mod 2).

If $a^3 + b^3$ is a multiple of 3: First, by Fermat's Little Theorem, we have $a^3 \equiv a$ (mod 3) and vice versa for $b$. As a result, we can conclude that $a + b \equiv 0$ (mod 3).

However, I don't know how to handle the $a^5 + b^5$. I've tried multiplying $(a^3 + b^3)(a^2 + b^2) = (a^5 + b^5) + a^2b^2(a + b)$, but that didn't seem to help. Can someone give me a few pointers on where to proceed?

Note: Testing a few examples, I think the answer is 6 ($(a, b) = (3, 3)$ yields $486$, $(a, b) = (2, 4)$ yields $1056$, ...). Rather than just the answer to this problem, I'm more concerned about the *proof methods* that I should develop to tackle problems similar to this in the future. I'd greatly appreciate if someone could provide a proof, relying mainly on theorems/lemmas related to modular arithmetic, that leads to the answer to this problem.

Comment: Examples are always good.  At least you can discover the answer empirically.  That makes it easier to solve.  (Note:  in this case, it is easy to go from the empirical result to a full proof).

Comment: @lulu Is my approach of multiplying $(a^3 + b^3)(a^2 + b^2)$ in the correct direction? I've been stuck on this for a while...

Comment: Again, start with examples.

Comment: Just compute the $\gcd$ of the values of $a^5+b^5$ for a couple of those solutions. The largest divisor that is sure to divide all must divide the $\gcd$ of any two. For example $\gcd(3^5+3^5, 4^5+2^4)$. That would prove that the number you want divides $6$.

Comment: For the other direction, solve the system $\begin{cases}a^2+b^2&\equiv0\pmod{6}\\a^3+b^3&\equiv0\pmod{6}\end{cases}$ and verify that for those $a^5+b^5\equiv0\pmod{6}$. That proves that $6$ divides all. Note that your examples are almost all solutions of this system already. The other is $(5,1)$ and swapping the values because the system is symmetric.

Comment: $2,3\mid a+b\iff 6\mid a+b$ by [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242). So $\bmod 6\!:\ a\equiv -b\Rightarrow a^5\equiv (-b)^5\equiv -b^5\,$ by the [Congruence Power Rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque Sorry, I don't see how this proves the answer? If $6 | a + b$ we can show that $6 | a^5 + b^5$ using the equation I tried working on in the question, but I don't see how you prove that $6$ is the *maximum* number to divide $a^5 + b^5$.

Comment: To show its the max look at the first few values and compute their gcd, as suggested above (a standard technique, e.g. see "Generally" [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614369/242) or see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4521113/242)).

Comment: i.e. $\,d\mid 486,1056\Rightarrow d\mid \gcd(486,1056) = 6\ \ $